# Test_and_Set() with wating

Tags: operating-system

```
    while(true) 
    {
        waiting[i] = true;
        while (waiting[i] && test_and_set(&lock)) ;
        waiting[i] = false;

        /* critical section */

        j = (i + 1) % n;
        while ((j != i) && !waiting[j]) 
            j = (j + 1) % n; 
        if (j == i) 
            lock = false; 
        else
            waiting[j] = false;

        /* remainder section */
    }
```

Consider a situation where Process P(i) enters into entry section. Initially lock is false. When it enters into entry section, the while loop terminates and the process P(i) enters into critical section with lock=true.

When it is out of critical section and finds a process P(j) which is waiting to enter critical section, say at the last line of code, i.e in remainder section there is a context switch and process P(j) enters into entry section.
At this position lock is true and waiting[j] also becomes true.
When it reaches the while loop, it should never end.
So how will the Process P(j) enters into critical section?

Am I doing something wrong?
Explain.

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that when `P(j)` enters **entry Section**, `lock` is `true` and `waiting[j]` is also `true`. Therefore, process `P(j)` is stuck in while loop(**called spin lock**).

Now assuming that `context switch` also occurs from process `P(j)` back to `P(i)`. We were out of **critical section** for process `P(i)` and now the following code is executed:

```
j = (i + 1) % n;
while ((j != i) && !waiting[j]) 
 j = (j + 1) % n; 
if (j == i) 
 lock = false;
```

So `j = i + 1` and the condition `(j != i) && !waiting[j]` becomes true( assuming waiting is initialized to false for each process).

Then `j` takes following values:

```
i + 2 , i + 3, ......0 , 1 , 2 , 3 , 4....i
```

wrap around of values occurs because of `%` operator.

when `j` becomes `i` condition `(j != i) && !waiting[j]` becomes `false` and while loop breaks and lock becomes `false` due to

```
if (j == i) 
 lock = false;
```

eventually process `P(i)` terminates and a `context switch` will occurr to process `P(j)` eventually, and **because test and set instruction returns old value** the condition

```
(waiting[i] && test_and_set(&lock))
```

will become `false` because `test_and_set(&lock)` returns `false` and `P(j)` will break out of the spinlock **and it will enter critical section**